# Declare an Object by Using an Object Initializer with variables

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, subprocess

I am currently working on VB.NET, .NET version 4.7.2 and Visual Studio 2019 (windows forms). I am pretty new to COM languages to spare if this is naive mistake. I am trying to declare objects with object initializer (equivalent) using variables. The reason I want to do it with variables is because those properties are stored in a text file. So I read those from the file as key / value pair (dictionary) and then assign it to variables to be used initializing an object. However, if gives me the below error

This is how I am assigning the variables from a dictionary.

```
    Dim Servername = MyKeyValues.Item("servername")
    Dim usr = MyKeyValues.Item("username")
    Dim pwd = MyKeyValues.Item("password")
```

I output the values on the terminal and it spits it out correctly with correct case as well (as I tried trim too just in case for any leading trailing spaces). But when I try to use it to initialize an objects, I get an error mentioned at the bottom.

```
    Dim objServer As New DSSDataSource
    objServer.Name = Trim(Servername) ' Servername.Text
    objServer.Type = EnumDSSDataSourceType.DssDataSourceTypeServer
    objServer.Location = Trim(Servername) 'Servername.Text
    objServer.Mode = EnumDSSConnectionMode.DssConnectionModeServerAccess
    objServer.AuthMode = EnumDSSAuthModes.DssAuthStandard
    objServer.login = Trim(usr) 'Login.Text
    objServer.Passwd = Trim(pwd) ' Pwd.Text
    objServer.Init()
```

However, when I just simply hardcode the same values, the object initialize just fine.

```
    Dim objServer As New DSSDataSource
    objServer.Name = "localhost" ' Servername.Text
    objServer.Type = EnumDSSDataSourceType.DssDataSourceTypeServer
    objServer.Location = "localhost" 'Servername.Text
    objServer.Mode = EnumDSSConnectionMode.DssConnectionModeServerAccess
    objServer.AuthMode = EnumDSSAuthModes.DssAuthStandard
    objServer.login = "test.usr" 'Login.Text
    objServer.Passwd = "xxx" ' Pwd.Text
    objServer.Init()
```

So I am not sure where I am going wrong.

[image]

Comment: And does `MyKeyValues.Item("servername")` contain "localhost" ?

Comment: There's no such thing as "declaring an object". You declare a variable, you create an object and you assign the object to the variable. Also, there's no object initialiser there. That is a specific thing and you're not using one. An example would be `Dim var As New SomeType With {.SomeProperty = someValue}`.

Comment: A `String` is a `String`, no matter where it comes from. If you hard-code a `String` and it works and then you get a `String` from elsewhere and it doesn't work, the `String` you got from elsewhere is different to the hard-coded `String`. That is 100% guaranateed. You might think that they're the same but they aren't. You need to look harder for that difference.

Comment: @CaiusJard - Yes, MyKeyValues.Item("servername") value is "localhost"

Comment: Above the line `objServer.Name = Trim(Servername) ' Servername.Text` write `MessageBox.Show("same " & (MyKeyValues.Item("servername") = "localhost")`- what does it show? Do same for login and password

Comment: @CaiusJard - It gives output as Same False. I am 100% sure both of you (jmcilhinney) are correct but it is just giving me a hard time to find out the difference. I also tried MyKeyValues("servername").ToString() but still does not match. I will start looking at the datatype and see if I can find anything.

Comment: If you pause in the debugger and point to the variable you should be able to see any invisible characters

Comment: For example this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyrHx.png a screenshot I took earlier of showing someone how to use the c# debugger - [the answer itself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66185109/1410664) might be worth a read if you haven't used the debugger much.. note that screenshot is c#, but I'm sure something shows up in vb.net too (I just can't find a good screenshot to make sure and I'm not near a pc to test )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by CaiusJard and jmcilhinney, it was indeed a string mismatch. It was probably due to a hidden character as it seems that when I read the file using ReadAll it also captures the carriage return.

I noticed that the length for `MessageBox.Show(Servername.Length)` and `MessageBox.Show("localhost".Length)` was different. I eventually had to replace the invisible character so that both match. It now works fine. Thank you both for the direction.

```
Dim Servername = MyKeyValues.Item("servername").Replace(Chr(13), "")
```

Comment: Better to Trim() before you store it in the dictionary..

Comment: You can use the built-in constant `vbCR` (I think) to replace character 13.  It will be a little more obvious what it's doing.